# Simulating noise around future known data points

Tags: time-series, standard-deviation, simulation

I am creating a simulation model of an electricity market. One of the important characteristics is fuel price.

Whilst I would like to set the future fuel price, I would like to sample from a distribution to add noise.

For example the time series `[14, 16, 13]` becomes `[14.5, 15.32, 13.4]` or something similar.

I would like to estimate this distribution from a historical dataset. The dataset in question is shown below, and the dataset is available [here](https://ufile.io/v15ho):

[image: Monthly natural gas prices]

I removed the trend by differencing of a single step, and 12 steps (yearly cycle) and now have a distribution:

[image: Distribution of differences]

Would I take the standard deviation of this and just apply it to my future time series `[14, 16, 13]` or would this be dependent on the difference between the previous point and previous 12 points?

Any other ideas are welcome!

Comment: In order to edit your own post, please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Comment: Why are you trying to add noise to your data?

Comment: Hi, my simulation takes into account a single year time step, but I would like to take into account the different prices that gas could be sold during this year. Therefore different agents/buyers buy at slightly different rates depending on when and how much gas they purchase.

Comment: Are you familiar with ARIMA models/Box-Jenkins? It's a more rigorous and well-known approach as opposed to something ad hoc

Comment: Yes I am familiar with them, but I was unsure how to extract the standard deviation from them. I thought ARIMA models were for predicting the next points.

Comment: I have fit an ARIMA model and now have a distribution of the residuals. Should I use that distribution when adding noise?